# Can I have macros in Java source files

Tags: java, macros

In my program I'm reading integers form console many times. Every time, I need to type this line.

```
new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
```

I'm used to C/C++ and I'm wondering if I can define something like

```
#define READINT Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
```

and then, in every place in my java program I can read form console as

```
int a = new READINT;
```

But I read form books Java does not support macros.

Someone please explain me why is it so, and can I do this in  any other way.

Comment: @Thomas Jungblut  yes. setting up a new scanner is unnecessary only. Now only I saw that. but can I have a way in java to replace symbolic names as mentioned

Comment: Wrapping in in a static method essentially does what you are asking. Regardless of whether it is a macro or not. Methods are the core part of Java, you cannot create symbolic names.

Comment: @AdamJMTech yes thank you. But can we create a library class which does this. (as the c++ compiler expands the object cin and links with system input)  Thereby , every java developers get a more robust coding

Comment: 1) http://manifold.systems/ https://github.com/manifold-systems/manifold 2) https://spoon.gforge.inria.fr/ https://github.com/INRIA/spoon

Answer (score 173, accepted):

You *can* but you *shouldn't*.

### The *shouldn't* part:

You *shouldn't* because using the pre-processor in that way [is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives) to start with, and there are better and more Java-idiomatic ways to solve this use case.

### The *can* part: (*)

Java itself doesn't support macros. On the other hand, you could pipe the source code through the [*C pre processor*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) (CPP for short) just like the C/C++ compile chain does.

Here's a demo:

**`src/Test.java`**:

```
#define READINT (new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextInt())

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = READINT;
    }
}
```

**`cpp` command:**

```
$ cpp -P src/Test.java preprocessed/Test.java
```

**Result:**

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = (new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextInt());
    }
}
```

**Compile:**

```
$ javac preprocessed/Test.java
```

### A better workaround:

You can write your own utility class with a static method instead:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class StdinUtil {
    public final static Scanner STDIN = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static int readInt() {
        return STDIN.nextInt();
    }
}
```

And when you want to use it, you can statically import the `readInt` method:

```
import static StdinUtil.readInt; 

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = readInt();
    }
}
```

(or do `static import StdinUtil.STDIN;` and use `STDIN.nextInt()`.)

### And finally, an anecdote

I myself used the CPP preprocessing approach on Java code once! I was creating a programming assignment for a course. I wanted to be able to easily extract a code skeleton out of the reference solution. So I just used a few `#ifdef`s to filter out the "secret" parts of the solution. That way I could maintain the reference solution, and easily regenerate the code skeleton.

---

This post has been rewritten as an article [here](http://programming.guide/java/macros-in-java-source-files.html).

---

<sup>(*) Since I hate answering questions with "you shouldn't". Besides, some future reader may have good reasons for wanting to use the `cpp` in conjunction with Java sources!</sup>

Comment: why think out of the box if you actually know there is no box? :)

Comment: However, note that stylistic elements, such as personal preferences for indentation, newlines, etc. may be lost, so use this method to make a final product, not, instead, a program that you would like others to be able to read and understand with ease

Comment: @Aalok, why would it be lost? `cpp` doesn't reformat the code.

Answer (score 14):

**No. Java (the language) does not support macros of any sort.**

However, certain constructs can be faked or wrapped. While the example is silly (*why are you creating a new scanner each time!?!?!*) the below shows how it can be achieved:

```
int nextInt() {
   return new Scanner(System.in).nextInt(); 
}
...
int a = nextInt();
int b = nextInt();
```

But *much* better:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = scanner.nextInt();
int b = scanner.nextInt();
```

Happy coding.

---

For comment:

*Static methods* can be called without needing an object to invoke them upon. However, in most cases one is *already in an object*. Consider:

```
public class Foo {
   static int nextIntStatic() {
     return 13;
   }

   int nextInt() {
     return 42;
   }

   void realMain () {
     // okay to call, same as this.nextInt()
     // and we are "in" the object
     int ni = nextInt();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // okay to call, is a static method
      int nis = nextIntStatic();
      Foo f = new Foo();
      f.realMain();
   }
}
```

Comment: but in java we cannot call methods without the object. am i correct. there nextint() is called without object

Comment: Make the method static if you like.

Answer (score 3):

Java doesn't support macros simply because the designers of Java chose not to include that functionality.  The longer answer is that Java doesn't have a preprocessor the way C/C++ does and cannot perform that functionality that the preprocessor normally would.  The way I would implement this is simply create a wrapper class that wraps up the `Scanner` constructor calls.  Perhaps something like

```
public static int readInt(){
  return new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
}
```

Or, better yet,

```
public class ScannerWrapper{
  private static Scanner instance = null;

  public static int readInt(){
   if (instance == null){
     instance = new Scanner(System.in);
   }

   return instance.nextInt();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Java does not support macros.  IIRC, the language designers felt that macros and the resultant preparser was an unnecessary and undesirable complication.

Use a function instead:

```
public int readInt(Scanner inp) {
    return inp.nextint();
    }
```

Elsewhere:

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

...


int a=readInt(input);
```

Note also, that I create the scanner once and reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no macro concept in Java. If you're doing that a lot, it's a bad idea to instantiate a new `Scanner` each time. Define a public static `Scanner` then reuse it each time:

```
public class YourClass {
  public static final Scanner SCANNER= new Scanner(System.in);
  ...
}

// Somewhere in your code
YourClass.SCANNER.nextInt();
```

Comment: ya thanks but public static final Scanner SCANNER= new Scanner(System.in);  I didnt understand this line. could you explain it

Comment: This is a constant which belongs to the class `YourClass` (not to its instances). It's public so you can use it anywhere if you import `YourClass`.

Comment: So, whether it is like a global variable? Or if i have to declare some global variables where i should do. please reply

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use C-Style macros then someone has written a pre-processor http://www.slashdev.ca/javapp/ I have no idea how good it is though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, for example, with [Java Primitive Specializations Generator](https://github.com/TimeAndSpaceIO/java-primitive-specializations-generator):

```java
/* define READINT //
new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
// enddefine */

...

int a = /* READINT */0/**/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Macros are text-level pre-processing tools that can be badly abused if not carefully designed. Example:

```
#define MULTIPLY( a, b ) ( a * b )
```

MULTIPLE(1+2,3+4) will have the result of (1+2*3+4)

Another example

```
#define SQUARE( a ) ((a) * (a))

int x = 5;
SQUARE(x++);
```

will increment x twice. ((x++) * (x++))

I think that Java language designers did not buy it for these reasons, because it is meant to be simple.

Answer (score -1):

Use a utility class and static import.

The utility class:

```
package my.utils;

public class ScannerUtils {
  private ScannerUtils() {}

  public static int readInt() {
    return new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
  }
}
```

Using the utility class:

```
package my.examples;

import static my.utils.ScannerUtils.*;

class Example {
  void foo() {
    int i = readInt();
  }
}
```

As others have said, you should probably cache your scanner, but that is a separate topic.

Comment: why not to include this utility class in general java library installion to make it world wide. it will be more robust . am i correct

Comment: From how I read your comment, you are wondering why such a method is not in core Java as a convenience API. There are many gaps in Java when it come to modeling common use cases conveniently. I don't have any perspective on whether this is such a case.

Comment: ... but I want to add that designing such an API to satisfy the entire world would be tricky. For example, should there be a new scanner created each time? What happens if/when System.in is swapped out with a new InputStream -- keep using the old one or use the new one?

Comment: Then for the efficient coding we have to use the traditional scan.nextInt() way only ya?.

Comment: @Muthu, this is a good question, and not one to be stuck in a comment thread. You should ask a separate question about the right idiom for constructing and caching Scanners.