# Passing parameters in @FindBy Page factory

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, serenity-bdd

Is there any way so that we can parameterize the string which we pass to create a page object using a page factory?

ex:

```
String v = "password";
@FindBy(name=v)
private WebElementFacade password_Field;
```

I am trying to push the string v into the @FindBy but I am getting an error.

I am getting
    The value for annotation attribute FindBy.name must be a constant expression.

Comment: Add stacktrace of exception in your question.

Comment: should work if you declare variable v with final keyword.

Comment: i agree it works if we use final keyword. but i want the value of v should be changeable. is there a way for that.

Comment: Annotation values must be resolvable at compile time. Needs to be a primitive or String. It cannot even be something referring to a properties file even when you put in a final keyword cause it will be resolved at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible. Please find the solution below:

In your `Page`, instead of using `@FindBy`, get the `WebElementFacade` using `find` method of the `Page` and then use it for operations.

For example: If you need to `click` on an element, please see the code below:

```
public void click(String elementId) {
    WebElementFacade element = find(ById.id(elementId));
    element.click();
}
```

This works perfectly for me. And the element id is coming all the way from `.story` examples.

Answer (score 0):

No, Unfortunately, it's not possible to send arguments to annotation (reference). Since Java annotations does not allow dynamic parameterization. The compiler evaluates annotation metadata at compile time. So, it must be present. Though there are work around for this.
Check this- [Java Annotations values provided in dynamic manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636201/java-annotations-values-provided-in-dynamic-manner)