# How to build the xpath for an dynamic element based on the input text

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

From the image attached, xpath for the delete button of the first account is

[image: accounts present in the screen to be added]

```
//*[@id='users-wrapper']/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/div/span[1]
```

I have the option to keep on adding the accounts which will result in increase of row count **tr** in the above xpath

Trying to achieve: When i add a new account with the screen name "twitter",i should get the row number of that account and build the xpath on the fly. so that various test cases can be written.

I can achieve this by writing a method. But how to achieve this in the page object model

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='userswrapper']/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/div/span[1]")
public List<WebElement> requiredChannel;
```

Please note that id's for these elements are generated dynamically

```html
<div class="container_box">
    <div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tabs-Twitter" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true">
                <a href="accountTwitter" title="#tabs-Twitter" class="source ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1"><img src="/includes/css/images/twitter.png" border="0">&nbsp;Twitter </a>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-fb" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false">
                <a href="FBAcct" title="#tabs-fb" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-2"><img src="/includes/css/images/facebook-icon.png" border="0">&nbsp;Facebook</a>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-pages" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-selected="false">
                <a href="pagesFBAcct" title="#tabs-pages" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-3" data-tooltip="#tabs-pages"><img src="/images/facebook-fan-page-icon-16.png" width="16px" height="16px" border="0">&nbsp;Facebook Pages</a>
            </li>
            <!-- put permission check later -->
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-fb-groups" aria-labelledby="ui-id-4" aria-selected="false">
                <a href="groupsFBAcct" title="#tabs-fb-groups" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-4"><img src="/images/facebook/facebook-group-icon-small.png" width="16px" height="16px" border="0">&nbsp;Facebook Groups</a>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-linkedin" aria-labelledby="ui-id-5" aria-selected="false">
                <a href="LinkedIn" title="#tabs-linkedin" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-5"><img src="/includes/css/images/linkedin.png" border="0">&nbsp;LinkedIn</a>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-companypage" aria-labelledby="ui-id-6" aria-selected="false">
                <a href="viewCompanyPagesLinkedIn" title="#tabs-companypage" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-6" data-tooltip="#tabs-companypage"><img src="/images/pagelinkedin-icon.png" border="0">&nbsp;LinkedIn Company Pages</a>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-youtube" aria-labelledby="ui-id-7" aria-selected="false">
                <a href="Youtube" title="#tabs-youtube" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-7"><img src="/images/Youtube-icon-16.png" border="0">&nbsp;YouTube</a>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-gppages" aria-labelledby="ui-id-8" aria-selected="false">
                <a href="GooglePlusPage" title="#tabs-gppages" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-8"><img src="/images/google_plus_pages.png" width="16px" height="16px" border="0">&nbsp;Google+ Pages</a>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-tumblr" aria-labelledby="ui-id-9" aria-selected="false">
                <a href="Tumblr" title="#tabs-tumblr" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-9"><img src="/images/tumblr.png" border="0">&nbsp;Tumblr</a>
            </li>
            <!-- added by sumanto on 5th nov 2014 -->
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-instagram" aria-labelledby="ui-id-10" aria-selected="false">
                <a href="Instagram" title="#tabs-instagram" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-10"><img src="/includes/css/images/instagram.png" border="0">&nbsp;Instagram </a>
            </li>
            <!-- end of addition by sumanto -->
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-Twitter" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">
            <div class="box">
                <table class="table table-striped  table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="15%"><b>User </b>
                            </th>
                            <th width="15%"><b>Screen Name </b>
                            </th>
                            <th width="30%"><b>Bio </b>
                            </th>
                            <th width="20%" align="center"><b>Added By </b>
                            </th>
                            <th width="10%" align="center"><b>View in Analytics </b>
                            </th>
                            <th width="10%" valign="middle"><b>Actions </b>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr id="twt_2279" tabindex="2279">
                            <td>
                                <div style="width:48px;float: left"><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/786866368457023488/fMEvHynN_normal.jpg">
                                </div>
                                <div style="float: left;margin-left: 8px;margin-top: 17px;">James heller</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>jheller360</td>
                            <td><span style="max-width:140px;"></span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div style="text-align: left;">
                                    <b>Name </b>:nagarjun&nbsp;reddy
                                    <br>
                                    <b>Short Name </b>:nagarjun
                                    <br>
                                    <b>Email Id </b>:nagarjun.reddy@in-rev.com
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p class="field switch">
                                    <label id="en2279" class="cb-enable selected" onclick="javascript:switchAnalytics(this);"><span>On</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label id="dis2279" class="cb-disable" onclick="javascript:switchAnalytics(this);"><span>Off</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <input id="M1VJeGpvRUNHMHhYeGFob0NNaGRBUT09" class="checkbox" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="middle">
                                <div style="margin-top:14px;">
                                    <a style="text-decoration: none;padding:3px 8px 8px 3px;" class="btn del" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="removeTwt('M1VJeGpvRUNHMHhYeGFob0NNaGRBUT09');" title="Delete Twitter Account">
                                    </a>
                                    <a style="text-decoration: none;padding:3px 8px 8px 3px;" class="btn addPeople" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="shareTwtAcc('M1VJeGpvRUNHMHhYeGFob0NNaGRBUT09','TWITTER');" title="Share Twitter Account">
                                    </a>
                                    <a style="text-decoration: none;padding:3px 8px 8px 3px;" class="btn reassociate" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="reAccTwtAcc('M1VJeGpvRUNHMHhYeGFob0NNaGRBUT09');" title="Re-Associate Twitter Account">
                                    </a>
                                    <span id="stat2279">
                                        <a style="text-decoration: none;padding:3px 8px 8px 3px;" class="btn deactivate" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="status('M1VJeGpvRUNHMHhYeGFob0NNaGRBUT09' ,'false','TWITTER',2279);" title="Deactivate"></a>
                                </span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="twt_2280" tabindex="2280">
                            <td>
                                <div style="width:48px;float: left"><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/636829932845293568/xkp-0_NW_normal.jpg">
                                </div>
                                <div style="float: left;margin-left: 8px;margin-top: 17px;">james.v</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>Lokesh2102V</td>
                            <td><span style="max-width:140px;"></span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div style="text-align: left;">
                                    <b>Name </b>:lokesh&nbsp;v
                                    <br>
                                    <b>Short Name </b>:lokesh
                                    <br>
                                    <b>Email Id </b>:lokesh.v@simplify360.com
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p class="field switch">
                                    <label id="en2280" class="cb-enable selected" onclick="javascript:switchAnalytics(this);"><span>On</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label id="dis2280" class="cb-disable" onclick="javascript:switchAnalytics(this);"><span>Off</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <input id="blNVRkU2d0ZzelNSN2F2dVZpT090dz09" class="checkbox" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="middle">
                                <div style="margin-top:14px;">
                                    <a style="text-decoration: none;padding:3px 8px 8px 3px;" class="btn del" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="removeTwt('blNVRkU2d0ZzelNSN2F2dVZpT090dz09');" title="Delete Twitter Account">
                                    </a>
                                    <a style="text-decoration: none;padding:3px 8px 8px 3px;" class="btn addPeople" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="shareTwtAcc('blNVRkU2d0ZzelNSN2F2dVZpT090dz09','TWITTER');" title="Share Twitter Account">
                                    </a>
                                    <a style="text-decoration: none;padding:3px 8px 8px 3px;" class="btn reassociate" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="reAccTwtAcc('blNVRkU2d0ZzelNSN2F2dVZpT090dz09');" title="Re-Associate Twitter Account">
                                    </a>
                                    <span id="stat2280">
                                        <a style="text-decoration: none;padding:3px 8px 8px 3px;" class="btn deactivate" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="status('blNVRkU2d0ZzelNSN2F2dVZpT090dz09' ,'false','TWITTER',2280);" title="Deactivate"></a>
                                </span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="twt_2281" tabindex="2281">
                            <td>
                                <div style="width:48px;float: left"><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/645847539762139137/kjzJmIQ2_normal.jpg">
                                </div>
                                <div style="float: left;margin-left: 8px;margin-top: 17px;">lok2102</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>lok2102</td>
                            <td><span style="max-width:140px;"></span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div style="text-align: left;">
                                    <b>Name </b>:lokesh&nbsp;v
                                    <br>
                                    <b>Short Name </b>:lokesh
                                    <br>
                                    <b>Email Id </b>:lokesh.v@simplify360.com
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p class="field switch">
                                    <label id="en2281" class="cb-enable selected" onclick="javascript:switchAnalytics(this);"><span>On</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label id="dis2281" class="cb-disable" onclick="javascript:switchAnalytics(this);"><span>Off</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <input id="U2pweG5yYlk5RTlNTnJabFJvc3dVdz09" class="checkbox" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="middle">
                                <div style="margin-top:14px;">
                                    <a style="text-decoration: none;padding:3px 8px 8px 3px;" class="btn del" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="removeTwt('U2pweG5yYlk5RTlNTnJabFJvc3dVdz09');" title="Delete Twitter Account">
                                    </a>
                                    <a style="text-decoration: none;padding:3px 8px 8px 3px;" class="btn addPeople" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="shareTwtAcc('U2pweG5yYlk5RTlNTnJabFJvc3dVdz09','TWITTER');" title="Share Twitter Account">
                                    </a>
                                    <a style="text-decoration: none;padding:3px 8px 8px 3px;" class="btn reassociate" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="reAccTwtAcc('U2pweG5yYlk5RTlNTnJabFJvc3dVdz09');" title="Re-Associate Twitter Account">
                                    </a>
                                    <span id="stat2281">
                                        <a style="text-decoration: none;padding:3px 8px 8px 3px;" class="btn deactivate" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="status('U2pweG5yYlk5RTlNTnJabFJvc3dVdz09' ,'false','TWITTER',2281);" title="Deactivate"></a>
                                </span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="twt_2283" tabindex="2283">
                            <td>
                                <div style="width:48px;float: left"><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/778556660532977664/FnGnlgiN_normal.jpg">
                                </div>
                                <div style="float: left;margin-left: 8px;margin-top: 17px;">cynthia simplify360</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>testpagemaush</td>
                            <td><span style="max-width:140px;"></span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div style="text-align: left;">
                                    <b>Name </b>:Maushumi&nbsp;Sen
                                    <br>
                                    <b>Short Name </b>:MaushumiAdmin
                                    <br>
                                    <b>Email Id </b>:maushumi.sen@simplify360.com
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p class="field switch">
                                    <label id="en2283" class="cb-enable selected" onclick="javascript:switchAnalytics(this);"><span>On</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label id="dis2283" class="cb-disable" onclick="javascript:switchAnalytics(this);"><span>Off</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <input id="Q1p2Qk5JQXVXbWFQTFMrLytiOU15QT09" class="checkbox" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="middle">
                                <div style="margin-top:14px;">
                                    <a style="text-decoration: none;padding:3px 8px 8px 3px;" class="btn del" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="removeTwt('Q1p2Qk5JQXVXbWFQTFMrLytiOU15QT09');" title="Delete Twitter Account">
                                    </a>
                                    <a style="text-decoration: none;padding:3px 8px 8px 3px;" class="btn addPeople" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="shareTwtAcc('Q1p2Qk5JQXVXbWFQTFMrLytiOU15QT09','TWITTER');" title="Share Twitter Account">
                                    </a>
                                    <a style="text-decoration: none;padding:3px 8px 8px 3px;" class="btn reassociate" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="reAccTwtAcc('Q1p2Qk5JQXVXbWFQTFMrLytiOU15QT09');" title="Re-Associate Twitter Account">
                                    </a>
                                    <span id="stat2283">
                                        <a style="text-decoration: none;padding:3px 8px 8px 3px;" class="btn deactivate" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="status('Q1p2Qk5JQXVXbWFQTFMrLytiOU15QT09' ,'false','TWITTER',2283);" title="Deactivate"></a>
                                </span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <button onclick="addTwtAccnt();" id="addTwtAccnt" class="connecttw" style="margin-top: 4px; min-width: 164px;">Add Twitter Account </button>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-fb" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true"></div>
        <div id="tabs-pages" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true"></div>
        <div id="tabs-fb-groups" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="ui-id-4" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true"></div>
        <div id="tabs-linkedin" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="ui-id-5" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true"></div>
        <div id="tabs-companypage" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="ui-id-6" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true"></div>
        <div id="tabs-youtube" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="ui-id-7" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true"></div>
        <div id="tabs-gppages" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="ui-id-8" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true"></div>
        <div id="tabs-tumblr" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="ui-id-9" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true"></div>
        <div id="tabs-instagram" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="ui-id-10" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true"></div>
        <div id="tabs-1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please share html of page for the screenshot

Comment: @thebadguy added the code in the question

Comment: FindBy annotation requires a constant value at compile time to work. You will need to use driver.findElement to get to the individual delete button. On a side note you should have a look at modifying your xpath to make it more direct instead of traversing the whole path. Any change in the structure and you will need to modify your automation code.

Comment: @Grasshopper, I have tried with taking the row as variable integer which works. But trying to figure out if the page object model, where all the elements repository are maintained, can provide the required xpath.

Comment: If you are planning to overcome limitations  in Java Annotations, below link might give some pointers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636201/java-annotations-values-provided-in-dynamic-manner. Implementing a method as suggested by @JeffC is also not a bad option.

Answer (score 0):

You would write a method in your page object that takes in the username that you want to delete.

```
public void DeleteTwitterAccount(String username)
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[.//div[text()='" + username + "']]//a[@title='Delete Twitter Account']")).click();
}
```

The XPath finds a `TR` that contains a `DIV` containing the desired user name. Once it has that, it drills down to the `A` tag that deletes and clicks it.

You would then call it like

```
SomePageObject somePageObject = new SomePageObject(driver);
somePageObject.deleteTwitterAccount("twitter");
```

Comment: Writing a different method, i'm aware of this. In page object model,identifier is given as **@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='userswrapper']/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/div/span[1]")
public List<WebElement> requiredChannel;**
Looks like no solution for the question i'm looking for.