# The value for annotation attribute Test.enabled must be a constant expression

Tags: java, reflection, testng

Basically, I wanted to use a constant boolean attribute of Context class which I have changed via reflection so that I can dynamically set the @annotated enabled for a testNG method in a TestNG class. The TestNG class has a static final attribute which is the same as the Context.DISBLE_TEST_CASES_IF_OLD_STACK. I have pasted the code below for the TestNG class and its method. **The end goal for me is to toggle the enabled value or basically disable the test based on the the context if its old environment or new environment**

```
 package com.abc.api.core.context;

    import java.lang.reflect.Field;
    import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;


    public class Context {
        public static final boolean DISBLE_TEST_CASES_IF_OLD_STACK = getConstantReflection();


        public static boolean getConstantReflection()
        {
            System.out.println(DISBLE_TEST_CASES_IF_OLD_STACK);
            try {
                setEnableFlagBasedOnStackForTestCases();
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(Context.DISBLE_TEST_CASES_IF_OLD_STACK);
            try {
                final Field fld = Context.class.getDeclaredField("DISBLE_TEST_CASES_IF_OLD_STACK");
                return (Boolean) fld.get( null );
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                return (Boolean) null;
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                return (Boolean) null;
            }
        }

        private static void setEnableFlagBasedOnStackForTestCases() throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException{


            Field f = Context.class.getDeclaredField("DISBLE_TEST_CASES_IF_OLD_STACK");
            f.setAccessible(true);

            //'modifiers' - it is a field of a class called 'Field'. Make it accessible and remove
            //'final' modifier for our 'CONSTANT' field
            Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField( "modifiers" );
            modifiersField.setAccessible( true );
            modifiersField.setInt( f, f.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL );

            if (TestcaseContext.getContext().equalsIgnoreCase(Context.OLD_STACK)) {
                f.setBoolean(null, false);
            }else {
                f.setBoolean(null, true);
            }
        }

    }
```

TESTNG CLASS AND METHOD example:

```
package com.abc.api.test.tests.TestA;

import com.abc.api.core.context.Context;

public class TestA extends TestCommon {

    private static final boolean ENABLE_DISABLE = Context.DISBLE_TEST_CASES_IF_OLD_STACK;

    /**
     * 
     */
    @BeforeTest
    void setPropertiesFile() {
      ......

    }

    /**
     * PATCH Positive Test Cases
     * 
     */

    @Test(priority = 11, enabled=ENABLE_DISABLE)
    public void testPositive1() {
        ......
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `DISBLE_TEST_CASES_IF_OLD_STACK` is not a constant variable. You won't be able to use that in an annotation.

Comment: But isn't reflection essentially modifying the static final value which is actually a constant attribute of the class. Hence I went through this path of using reflection.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636201/java-annotations-values-provided-in-dynamic-manner

Comment: The compiler is permitted to copy constant variable values directly and never actually read them at runtime, so this wouldn't work even if it did compile. See e.g. https://ideone.com/WT9j9z

Answer (score 2):

To the end goal of selectively disabling testcases, you can use TestNgs IAnnotationTransformer to control the enabled flag.  It will be run before each @Test annotated method and can control it's execution.

eg.

```
public class DemoTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {
  public void transform(ITest annotation, Class testClass,
      Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod)
  {
    if (condition) {
        annotation.setEnabled(false/true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I ended up doing. However, for some reason when I annotated the TestNG class with the listener class the listener was not invoked. I had to use the listener through xml in the test suite, which is kind of a bummer because I wanted to apply this listener to just this particular class. Also, I found out that I could just use groups and exclude and include them as per need.