# Using a constant class to create test descriptions for Testng test description

Tags: java, testng

Our automation framework is written in Java and uses Testng. We use the `@Test` annotation to mark out our tests and provide the groups and a description for the test which we write in Gherkin. We use the test report created by Serenity

I have been trying to create a static constant class that we can use to build a test description so that it handle HTML tags rather than putting this into the `String` itself so its easier to read and so any HTML format that the test report uses can be done within this class rather than each

For example:

```
@Test( groups = { TestGroup.One, TestGroup.TWO }, description = 
                "<b>Given</b> I am in Scenario One</br>" +
                "<b>When</b>I do something</br>" +
                "<b>Then</b>I get a result")
        protected void testScript() {
    ...
    }
```

would actually look like:

```
@Test( groups = { TestGroup.One, TestGroup.TWO }, description = 
            TestDescription
                .given("I am in Scenario One")
                .when("I do something")
                .then("I get a result");)
    protected void testScript() {
...
}
```

The code I currently have:

```
public final class TestDescription {

    private static String description = "";

    public static String given(final String given) {

        return "<b>Given</b>" + given + "</br>";
    }

    public static TestDescription when(final String when) {

        description = description + "<b>When</b>" + when + "</br>";
        return null;
    }

    public static TestDescription then(final String then) {

        description = description + "<b>Then</b>" + then + "</br>";
        return null;
    }

    public static TestDescription and(final String and) {

        description = description + "<b>And</b>" + and + "</br>";
        return null;
    }

    public static String build() {

        return description;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Annotations values provided in dynamic manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636201/java-annotations-values-provided-in-dynamic-manner)

Comment: What is the question you have ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotation attribute values must be compile-time constants in Java. See [allowed expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) in Java documentation.

In TestNG the formatting of description attribute can be done through creating a custom [TestNG `@Test` annotation transformer](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers).

Sample code:

```
public class MyAnnotationTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {

    private static final String GIVEN = "given: ";
    private static final String WHEN = "when: ";
    private static final String THEN = "then: ";

    @Override
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
        if (testMethod != null) {
            String description = annotation.getDescription();
            if (description != null && !description.isEmpty()) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (String item : description.split("\\|")) {
                    if (item.startsWith(GIVEN)) {
                        sb.append("<b>Given</b> ").append(item.substring(GIVEN.length())).append("<br />");
                    } else if (item.startsWith(WHEN)) {
                        sb.append("<b>When</b> ").append(item.substring(WHEN.length())).append("<br />");
                    } else if (item.startsWith(THEN)) {
                        sb.append("<b>Then</b> ").append(item.substring(THEN.length())).append("<br />");
                    } else {
                        sb.append(item).append("<br />");
                    }
                }
                description = sb.toString();
                annotation.setDescription(description);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then the method would be annotated like this:

```
@Test( groups = { TestGroup.ONE, TestGroup.TWO }, description =
        "given: I am in Scenario One" +
        "|when: I do something" +
        "|then: I get a result")
protected void testScript() {
    //...
}
```

Note: when implementing custom TestNG listeners, we need to make sure theyare used by TestNG. (Listeners can be specified in the TestNG XML test suite or [through other means](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#listeners-testng-xml).)

The resulting description in this case would be:

```
<b>Given</b> I am in Scenario One<br /><b>When</b> I do something<br /><b>Then</b> I get a result<br />
```

I hope this helps.