# Pass values from custom annotation (@TestDisplayName) attributes to another annotation (@DisplayName)

Tags: java, junit, annotations

I am looking for a way to standarize display name in Unit Test using `@DisplayName(value = "...")`

I would like to create custom annotation:

```
@TestDisplayName(method = "testMethod", when = "input is null", expected = "should return something"
```

and use this custom annotation should use JUnit's [@DisplayName](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.3/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/DisplayName.html) annotation in this way (inserts `@TestDisplayName`'s arguments between constant strings):

```
@DisplayName(value = "Method: " + TestDisplayName.method + " - When: " + TestDisplayName.when + " - Expected: " + TestDisplayName.expected);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the previous stackoverflow conversations i understand that there is no way to pass the values for an Annotation dynamically.
[Java Annotations values provided in dynamic manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636201/java-annotations-values-provided-in-dynamic-manner#10636320)
please check on this page whether you are trying the same here.