# How to handle dynamic elements in Page Object Model in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, parameters, pageobjects, page-factory

Is it possible to handle dynamic elements in Page Object Model?

Example:

```
package pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;

public class Home_Page {
    WebDriver driver;

    public Home_Page(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using = "//input[@name = '%s']")
    public WebElement inputField;
}
```

I want to pass the name attribute value of input, from my test method.

```
package scripts;

@Test
public void test(){
        driver.get("url");
        Home_Page homepage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Home_Page.class);
        homepage.inputField.sendKeys("xpathParameter", "sendKeysVal"); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to implement the way you want since there is no way to dynamically pass a value to annotation in Java - [Java Annotations values provided in dynamic manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636201/java-annotations-values-provided-in-dynamic-manner).

However, you can achieve the same replacing your|class field + annotation| with |method|:

```
package pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;

public class Home_Page {
    WebDriver driver;

    public Home_Page(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public WebElement inputField(String name) {
       return this.driver.findElement(String.format(By.xpath("//input[@name = '" + name + "']");
    }
}


package scripts;

    @Test
    public void test(){
        driver.get("http://play.krypton.infor.com");
        Home_Page homepage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Home_Page.class);
        homepage.inputField("xpathParameter").sendKeys("sendKeysVal"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something of this sort should be useful in case you want to find an element using `findBy` and provide a `pagename` dynamically.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
public class CreateLocators {
    public static By buildByObject(String pageName, String fieldName) {
        try {
            Class<?> clas = Class.forName("pageobjects." + pageName);
            Object obj = clas.newInstance();
            return new Annotations(obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName)).buildBy();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

In `StepDef`, you should be doing like:

```
byElem = CreateLocators.buildByObject(pageName, desiredElementNameInPO);
        elem = driver.findElement(byElem);
        elem.click();
```

Comment: so many rule and restrictions in adding a small piece of code :)  I will take some time to get hang of it

Comment: Hi Das, is there a way I can provide someone  a link  to gitlab so that they can see the all the project file?