# Read an environment property inside a Java annotation?

Tags: java, spring

I have this code but I dont want the `fixedRate` flag to be hardcoded to 20000. Is it possible to put the 20000 in a property file and read that value inside my `@Scheduled` annotation?

```
@CacheEvict(allEntries = true, value = "fooResponse")
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 20000)
public void reportCacheEvict() {

    logger.debug("Doing Stuff on a fixed rate Schedule");
}
```

Comment: No. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636201/java-annotations-values-provided-in-dynamic-manner)

Comment: That can be done with the `fixedRateString` attribute. That can take a SpEL or value expression to be resolved at startup.

Comment: An example to Deinums answere would be: @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "#{schedulerProperties.crawlRefreshInterval}") where schedeulerProperties is a PropertyBean