# Use SpEL in custom annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-annotations, java-annotations

I have a simple custom annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Service
public @interface SampleDefinition {
    String description();
    String orderNr() default "";
}
```

I need to make a description() configurable which means I need something like:

```
@SampleDefinition(description = "Value from properties ${expirationDays:120}")
```

I know I cannot use SpEL just like I did in the example. However, is there a way to inject Spring property value into this description?

Comment: Please read through : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10636320/4214241