# How to write a locator using resource-id in appium

Tags: automation, appium, android-uiautomator

```
@AndroidFindBy(id="com.com-uat:/id")
private MobileElement id;
```

Here my resource id has a packageName, but my packageName changes depending on the environment
for ex `Uat- com.com-uat` `prod- com.com.prod`.

Now how do I make it dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

There is [no way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10636320/4103101) to dynamically generate a string in annotation.

I checked AndroidFindBy annotation and I don't see an easy way to extend it the way it will support different values based on env.

But generally you are not required to pass package name in a value, `id` should be enough:

```
@AndroidFindBy(id="nome_button")
private MobileElement homeButton;
```

should work the same way as if you define it

```
@AndroidFindBy(id="com.com-uat:id/home_button")
private MobileElement homeButton;
```

You need to provide package when it is Android native element, but in that case it will be the same for UAT and PROD:

```
@FindBy(id = "android:id/text1")
private WebElement textView;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it really helped me. I learnt something new