# Java.Selenium. How to put not constant variable inside of xpath?

Tags: java, selenium, attributes, page-factory

I am working with Java Selenium. And I need to put String line `computeEngine.getMachineSeries()` from properties inside of my xpath. How can I do this?

```
 @FindBys({@FindBy(xpath = "//md-option//div[@class='md-text ng-binding'][contains(text(), '"+computeEngine.getMachineSeries()+"')]")})
    List<WebElement> seriesOptionNOne;
```

I cant use this code above, because of this error: "Attribute value must be constant". How can I do this in another way?

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following solution:

```
String myString = computeEngine.getMachineSeries();
@FindBys({@FindBy(xpath = "//md-option//div[@class='md-text ng-binding'][contains(., '"+ myString +"')]")})
List<WebElement> seriesOptionNOne;
```

Comment: I already try that. It still be "not constant".

Comment: @DMart I would have liked a comment for the downvote so that I could have improved my answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Not possible:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10636320/1387701

> There is no way to dynamically generate a string used in an
> annotation. The compiler evaluates annotation metadata for
> RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME annotations at compile time, but
> GENERIC_GENERATED_NAME isn't known until runtime. And you can't use
> generated values for annotations that are RetentionPolicy.SOURCE
> because they are discarded after compile time, so those generated
> values would never be known.