# kotlin possible use annotation dynamic parameter inside custom annotation?

Tags: java, kotlin, annotations, dynamic-properties

[What I would like to do kotlin]

1. wrap an existing annotation
2. use dynamic parameters

[code]

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD)
@Inherited
@Documented
@Cacheable(cacheNames = {custom_properties}, cacheManager = "cacheManager") // exist java or kotlin annotation
annotation class CustomCache(val custom_properties:Array<String>) //custom annotation and 
parameters
```

do you have a solution?
Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic parameters"? Do you mean vararg?

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636201/java-annotations-values-provided-in-dynamic-manner ?