# when using @Value spring annotation, is it possible to leverage some sort of string interpolation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

Can I do something like this?

```
private final static String myVar = "health.xyz.throughput";

@Value("${{myVar}:10}")   // doesn't work of course
private Integer healthThroughput;
```

Essentially `myVar` key is getting used elsewhere so wanted to see if it can be moved to a constant?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636201/java-annotations-values-provided-in-dynamic-manner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible:

```
  private static final String myVar = "health.xyz.throughput";

  @Value("${" + myVar + ":10}")
  private Integer healthThroughput;
```

Also you can use:

```
  private static final String myVar = "${health.xyz.throughput:10}";

  @Value(myVar)
  private Integer healthThroughput;
```