# Insert an environment variable in an annotation attribute value in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have been trying to populate an annotation attribute value at runtime, but it is not able to compile.
The error is:
`Attribute value must be constant`

this is the code:

```
public static final String QUEUE_NAME = System.getenv("QUEUE_NAME");
@JmsListener(destination = QUEUE_NAME ,containerFactory = "jmsListenerFactory")
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You will be able to find out the answer in this post [Annotation Dynamic Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636201/java-annotations-values-provided-in-dynamic-manner#:~:text=There%20is%20no%20way%20to%20modify%20the%20properties%20of%20an,two%20ways%20to%20do%20this.&text=When%20you%20read%20that%2C%20you,SPEL%20(Spring%20expression%20language).)

Comment: @TheNor have you been able to try my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `@JmsListener(destination = "${QUEUE_NAME}" ,containerFactory = "jmsListenerFactory")`

At least it works with `@Value("${QUEUE_NAME}")` :)

Happy coding.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Do not hesitate to accept this answer as a correct one when you have time. Thanks