# How to Implement Macro in JAVA using Eclips / IntelliJ

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, macros, intellij-idea

So the idea is to support #Macro in java. Not only in the final result but also during compile time. So all the injections and code completion will work properly.

To add the macro functionality to java we can use [CPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor).

**`src/Test.java`**:

```
#define READINT (new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextInt())

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = READINT;
    }
}
```

**`cpp` command:**

```
$ cpp -P src/Test.java preprocessed/Test.java
```

**Result:**

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = (new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextInt());
    }
}
```

**Compile:**

```
$ javac preprocessed/Test.java
```

*Tnx to aioobe for the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6525113/1129332) idea.*

How ever this will only allows us to compile macros, we need a way to use it in code time, so if I do some thing like this:

```
#define PASTE2(a, b) a##b
#define PASTE(a, b) PASTE2(a, b)
#define setParameter(type,name) private type name;public type PAST(get,name)(){return name;}
```

**Usage:**

```
setParameter(int, value)
```

**Will produce:**

```
int value;public int getvalue(){return value;}
```

I want the compile to autocomplete this method. So it will know the class contains a getter *getvalue()* from type *int*

Also there are java [annotations](http://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/annotation-processors/) that can work in compile time, but I am not sure that it's possible with them.

Comment: This sounds to me like you would need the IDEs themselves to support macros...

Comment: One of the reasons that Java programs are relatively easy to maintain is the _lack_ of a preprocessor as the code is guaranteed to behave as you would expect.  This is deliberately.  That said, you should look into a project Lombok.  http://projectlombok.org

Comment: Nonono. Please use OOP. No code generation. If you need to have a common method in a bunch of places just use inheritance.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen please add this as an answer and explain to us this even possible.

Comment: Java programs manage to be just as bad as C programs even without a preprocessor.

Comment: Wow, it's not like anyone's recommending the overuse/abuse of OOP at all...

Comment: @dimoniy Don’t use inheritance for code reuse. In most cases an actual design suffices.

Comment: If you want a language that runs on the JVM and has a powerful macro system, you should look at [Clojure](http://clojure.org/).

Comment: @rightfold Lisp macros are quite different from preprocessor macros.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen In that they are actually sane and powerful, indeed. Never use preprocessor macros.

Comment: @rightfold and they are two very different things.  Lisp Macros are not a replacement for CPP Macros.  Consider having a look at http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman I'll leave writing a full answer to others.  If what you want is simply to have shorthand notation for getters/setters then look at Lombok.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen you know there is no thank you here, my of doing this is approving your answer. That what I wanted to tell you before: Tnx, this is it!