# How to ignore specified keywords in Java

Tags: java, exception, keyword

I understand what I am asking for in the following question has almost no practical application, but I want to know if it is possible to do in Java.

I want to be able to define  a`throws` declaration with two words (the first word to be ignored and the second word to be treated as a valid exception type, which it will be).

So basically I want a method signature that looks like this to compile:

```
public void foo() throws A Fit {}
```

Where the word '`A`' is simply ignored and then I would have `Fit` defined as a custom exception (as you would normally do this) like:

```
public class Fit extends Exception {
  public Fit(String msg) {
    super(msg);
  }
}
```

So in essence I am asking if I can somehow tell Java to ignore a specific textual 'keyword' (in this instance '`A`'). Thus, define keyword '`A`' to do nothing. I know you can do this in C by defining keywords via `#define`, but does Java offer this capability in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No. Java is [pretty strict and straightforward about keywords](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html)

You can play with ANTLR and Java's Grammar to achieve something similar, as shown by this other SO answer: [Add or modify keywords in java language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25623697/add-or-modify-keywords-in-java-language)